# View the arguments of a POST-Request in Google App Engine logs

Tags: http, google-app-engine, post, http-post, httprequest

I have a server running over Google App Engine.

I am viewing my server's request-log via the console.

They are located under `Google Cloud Platform --> Stackdriver Logging --> Logs`.

I would like to view the arguments of a POST-Request.

---

With a GET-Request it is easy, as they are visible in the title of the entry.

They are also viable in the body of the entry, under `protoPayload --> resource`.

With a POST-Request, however, they are nowhere to be found.

Here are my options:

- `metadata`
- `protoPayload`
- `insertId`
- `log`
- `httpRequest`
- `operation`

None of these options seem to contain the arguments of the request.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551320/1382251), I understand that they should be within the request-body.

How can I find them within GAE logs?

Comment: I don't believe POST parameters are automatically displayed in logs due to security reasons.  You don't want username/passwords that users may post on a site available in log files.  You can explicitly output request params to logs from app engine code using logger.info in your code.

Comment: @JeffDeskins: OK, so that would be considered as **application-logs**, not request-logs, right?

Comment: @barakmanos, the two logs are one and the same.  Using `'logging.info` will add additional information to the Stackdriver logs that you are looking at.

Comment: @Kekito: As far as I understand, the request-log comes automatically (i.e., generated for every request that the server receives), and the application-log is (indeed) generated from my `logging` operations. So these logs are different to my understanding. Is that correct? And will I have to do `logging` in order to get the arguments of any POST-Request? Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos, no that is incorrect.  A `logging.info()` shows up in the Stackdriver request logs and that is the only way to see POST arguments.  Just try it!

Comment: @Kekito: I have, and it does show up (with an `i` left to it). Was hoping that there could be a way without `logging`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

**post request data isn't shown in request logs.**

In your app, you must explicitly log it

```
logging.log(myRequest.PostData)
```

Edit: just be careful logging sensitive customer information.

Comment: Where should this be applied @robert king? I'm not able to find it.

Comment: inside your request handler. depends what web framework you use but search for how to log

Comment: you could also try "print", although logging is better

Comment: I've searched a lot and I still trying to accomplish this. I'm running a PHP app with a flexible environment. Docs are really poor. Where should I look at? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/logs/
seems you can use echo or syslog