# How do I enable POST request body in Google Cloud Platform Logs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, measurement-protocol

I've been studying logs in Logs Explorer in Google Cloud Platform and noticed that available logs don't show the body of a POST request, which is crucial for my task (I run Google Tag Manager Server-Side and need to study logs of all inbound Measurement Protocol requests). Is there a way to enable the body contents for requests like this one?

[image: Log Example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055216/view-the-arguments-of-a-post-request-in-google-app-engine-logs ? I don't know if something changed since 2017...

Comment: Which service are you using? App Engine?

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere Yes, I use App Engine Flexible

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in feature in GCP Logging to do this just as [norbjd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7804058/norbjd) said.

Only thing that's being [logged by default are GET requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs#understanding_request_log_fields) and only the first line:

> First line of the request, containing method, path, and HTTP version. Example: GET / HTTP/1.1

Have a look at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38055216/12257250) and then the  [fallowing comments fallowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055216/view-the-arguments-of-a-post-request-in-google-app-engine-logs#comment63549959_38055216):

> A `logging.info()` shows up ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055216/view-the-arguments-of-a-post-request-in-google-app-engine-logs#comment63567449_38055216))

> I have, and it does show up (with an i left to it) in the Stackdriver request logs and that is the only way to see POST arguments ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055216/view-the-arguments-of-a-post-request-in-google-app-engine-logs#comment63576075_38055216))

You may also try a [solution from the next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43510829/12257250):

> **post request data isn't shown in request logs.**
>
> In your app, you must explicitly log it
>
> `logging.log(myRequest.PostData)`
>
> Edit: just be careful logging sensitive customer information.